# Swift 3 - What does this mean?

Tags: swift, swift3

I converted my project to Swift 3, I am having trouble with the following piece of code, it seems that this ( >>>-) is no longer used in Swift 3.  What does  >>>- actually mean? and how to use it in Swift 3?

```
fileprivate func addImageToView(_ view: UIView, image: UIImage?) -> UIImageView? {
guard let image = image else { return nil }

let imageView = Init(UIImageView(image: image)) {
  $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  $0.alpha = 0
}
view.addSubview(imageView)

// add constraints
[NSLayoutAttribute.left, .right, .top, .bottom].forEach { attribute in
  (view, imageView) >>>- { $0.attribute = attribute }
}
imageView.layoutIfNeeded()

return imageView
```

}

Comment: That is a custom operator that work on view constraints, it the same as these [Constraint+](https://github.com/xhamr/fave-button/blob/master/Source/Helpers/Constraints%2B.swift), but what is the error ?

Comment: Hi @xhamr the error is result of operator is unused - It only started showing up after Swift 3, how can I fix it?

Comment: The author of the library where the operator is, need to mark the method with `@discardableResult` to comply with swift3 on function which it result might not be used

Comment: Thanks, @xhamr ! That makes sense, but is there anything I can do in the meantime? :(

Answer (score 0):

The `>>>-` returns a value. Before Swift 3, the compiler did not warn you if you did not assign the return value of a function or method to anything. Starting in Swift 3, you will get an error if the return value of a function or method (including operators) is unused. A library author can fix this by adding the `@discardableResult` annotation, but in the meantime you will have to change that line of code to:

```
let _ = (view, imageView) >>>- { $0.attribute = attribute }
```

Comment: Thanks @mipadi! I tried your solution this way:
 [NSLayoutAttribute.left, .right, .top, .bottom].forEach { attribute in
      let _ = (view, imageView) >>>- { $0.attribute = attribute }
    }
    imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
and I am getting this error:  Cannot convert value of type '(UIView, UIImageView)' to expected argument type '(_, _)'

Comment: @aaghanim: If the return value is a tuple, you probably need `let (_,_) = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact this answer can solve the issue in your side, there still a need to the author of the library to make some changes on his side.

The problem is because swift removed completely the `var` from function parameters and somehow that change is affecting the param you're receiving in the closure. (It seem a bug to me). You need to figure it out what is the type of the `inout` param the library is passing to the operator closure, and declare it as `inout` in your call. let's say that type is `Constraint` (this might not be the same as the library), then on you:

```
(view, imageView) >>>- { (i : inout Constraint) in
     i.attribute = attribute
}
```

But again, the author might still need to make some changes in the operator implementation as well.

Comment: Thanks, @xhamr! I got rid of the errors this way, but the app still doesn't work :( Crashes on that class